# $exists is not working with $match stage in MongoDb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I am working on Mongodb v3.6. I am trying to run a query regarding customer reviews. In this query I need only that documents which have some value of "review" field. For this I have executed following query:

```
db.customer_reviews.aggregate([
{$match: {rating: { $gte: 3}, review: {$ne: "", $exists: true}}},
{$lookup: {
"localField": "uid",
"from": "users",
"foreignField": "_id",
"as": "review_fields"
}},
{"$unwind": "$review_fields"},
]).pretty()
```

I have some documents which do not contain review field or having value as empty string, like:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "uid" : 8,
        "booking_id" : 1,
        "rating" : 4.5,
        "review" : "This is very fast.",
        "rated_by" : 1,
        "dont_send_notification" : false
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "uid" : 8,
        "booking_id" : 1,
        "rating" : 5,
        "review" : "",
        "rated_by" : 1,
        "dont_send_notification" : false
}
{
        "_id" : 3,
        "uid" : 8,
        "booking_id" : 17,
        "rating" : 5,
        "review" : "This team work's very fast and well. And I really appriciated there work and hard work. I really like this software.",
        "rated_by" : 1,
        "dont_send_notification" : false
}
{
        "_id" : 7,
        "uid" : 8,
        "booking_id" : 21,
        "rating" : 5,
        "rated_by" : 1,
        "dont_send_notification" : false
}
{
        "_id" : 8,
        "uid" : 8,
        "booking_id" : 21,
        "rating" : 5,
        "rated_by" : 1,
        "dont_send_notification" : false
}
```

But in this query, I am still getting documents that either do not contain review field or having blank value for it.
I have gone through the documentation of $exists operator.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/operator/query/exists/

I have also tried to run the query without $ne operator which results the same as before. Please guide what am I doing wrong or missing something ?

Thanks!

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As in it actually works for everyone else, so show a reproducible case and someone will look into it. Or you might spot a mistake in being able to present a reproducible case. That's why we ask for them.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I have edited the post with reproducible code.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur : can you post a couple of docs from customer_reviews and users collection

Comment: But what is your claim? You just gave us 4 documents. Your `$exists` usage here will return 3 of them. The one document that does not return is the one without the field. That's how it's supposed to work. The `$ne` of course excludes 1 more. So only 2 get returned.

Comment: I have tried running it in v3.6, it is returning all of them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
db.customer_reviews.aggregate([
{$match: {rating: { $gte: 3}, review: {$exists: true, $nin: [ "", null ]}}},
{$lookup: {
"localField": "uid",
"from": "users",
"foreignField": "_id",
"as": "review_fields"
}},
{"$unwind": "$review_fields"},
]).pretty()
```

Ideally, you should have a validation before you write to your `customer_reviews`. The field `review` should exist only if some user has given a valid review. That way all you have to do is     `{$match: {rating: { $gte: 3}, review: {$exists: true}}}`